# JSON-Data Date_Format doesnt show

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, date, date-format

Hello and sorry my bad english :-)

i have a little problem with my json data.

I have a mysql database. in this database i have safed data in a date format.
But the date format is in this format: YYYY.MM.DD.
I need the Format DD.MM.YYYY.
Well, i changed the request in this way:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT event_name, DATE_FORMAT(beginn,'%d.%m.%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(ende,'%d.%m.%Y') FROM party WHERE ende >= CURDATE()ORDER BY beginn ASC");
```

Now i get this string with the right date-format

```
{"sommer":[{"event_name":"testevent","DATE_FORMAT (beginn, '%d.%m.%Y')":"28.01.2015","DATE_FORMAT (ende, '%d.%m.%Y')":"30.01.2015"}]}
```

But now i have the problem, with my javascript.
Before i did this with: DATE_Format (beginn,'%d.%m.%Y'), i got the date (but not in the right format).
Now i got nothing.

here my javascript:

```
var url="party.php";
var activitydetail = sessionStorage.activitydetail;
$.getJSON(url,function(json){

$.each(json.sommer,function(i,item){

$('<li><a href="#'+item.event_name+'"> '+item.DATE_FORMAT (beginn, '%d.%m.%Y')+' - '+item.event_name+'</a></li>').appendTo('#accor2');

        });



    });
```

The function doesn't work any more with `'+item.beginn+'` and doesn't work with `'+item.DATE_FORMAT(beginn, '%d.%m.%Y')+'`

Anybody knows a solution?

A big thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't prepared your json string good enough, so you have:

`{"sommer":[{"event_name":"testevent","DATE_FORMAT (beginn, '%d.%m.%Y')":"28.01.2015","DATE_FORMAT (ende, '%d.%m.%Y')":"30.01.2015"}]}`

that's mean that your property name is `"DATE_FORMAT (ende, '%d.%m.%Y')"`

but in your js code you are trying to get:

`item.beginn` that has no sense.

So my suggestion is to change your json string (I guess somewhere on php side) to:

`{"sommer":[{"event_name":"testevent","beginn":"28.01.2015","ende":"30.01.2015"}]}`

Probably you can do that right in sql query, if I see the way you do this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT event_name, DATE_FORMAT(beginn,'%d.%m.%Y') as beginn, DATE_FORMAT(ende,'%d.%m.%Y') as ende FROM party WHERE ende >= CURDATE()ORDER BY beginn ASC");
```

and I think you will be able to fix your js much easier.